# обрезка строки по 1 символу с записью в массив

Tags: javascript, строки

есть строка
'abccdddeeeee'

я хочу получить из нее массив вида ['a', 'b', 'c', 'cc', 'd', 'dd', 'ddd', 'e', 'ee', 'eee', 'eeee', 'eeeee']

в чем здесь проблема?

```
let str = 'abccdddeeeee';
let arrStr = str.match(/([a-z])(\1)*/g);
let arrPars = [];

arrStr.forEach((el) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        let n = el.length;
        while (n >= 0) {
            arrPars.push(el.substr(0, el - n));
            n--;
        }
    }
});
console.log(arrStr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде есть такие недочёты:

1. `(\1)*` в регулярке избыточно, достаточно `\1*` — хоть это не влияет на результат, это убирает лишнее запоминание скобок и проясняет регулярку.
2. `for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {` — этот цикл тоже лишний, так вы зачем-то умножаете проходы по символам каждой группы и в результат попадают лишние значения. Достаточно цикла `while`.
3. `let n = el.length;` — тут у вас готовится ошибка на единицу, в результат попадут пустые строки (`substr` первый раз вырежет строку нулевой длины).
4. `el.substr(0, el - n)` — тут скорее всего вместо второго `el` (строки) имелось в виду `el.length`.
5. `console.log(arrStr);` — видимо, имелось в виду `console.log(arrPars);`.

Вот так ваш вариант вроде работает:

```js
let str = 'abccdddeeeee';
let arrStr = str.match(/([a-z])\1*/g);
let arrPars = [];

arrStr.forEach((el) => {
    let n = el.length - 1;
    while (n >= 0) {
        arrPars.push(el.substr(0, el.length - n));
        n--;
    }
});
console.log(arrPars);
```

А этот просто для коллекции.

```js
const str = 'abccdddeeeee';

const arrStr = str.match(/([a-z])\1*/g);

const arrPars = arrStr.flatMap(
  el => [...el].map((char, i) => char.repeat(i + 1))
);

console.log(arrPars);
```